# How to let $ionicFilterBar only search on `enter` key hit or onblur event instead of keypress?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-filter-bar

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar) to implement **ionicfilterBar** on my ionic 1 project. The default function in this tutorial I understood that the searching were during typing. How I want to make it custom so that the search process only when user hit `enter key` from the keypad or `onblur`?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Have nice Friday!

```
$scope.showFilterBar = function () {
    filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
        items: $scope.items,
        update: function (filteredItems, filterText) {
            $scope.items = filteredItems;
            if (filterText) {

                //Start custom function 
                $rootScope.live_preview_question_ids = filterText;

                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                        disableBack: false
                    });
                    $state.go('live-preview',{
                        indexId: 0
                    })
               // End custom function
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you set up a plunker with a small example? Would be much easier to help.